# Can you use this.props.history.push to pass props to a different component than the pathname says?

Tags: reactjs, variables, react-router, react-props, react-component

I am using this.props.history.push to pass props to components after submitting a form.

The submission of a form takes user to the home page (/home) but it also needs to pass props to NavBar component which is not included in the react-router routes.

```
 this.props.history.push({
    pathname: '/home',
    propOne: propOneValue // <-- this prop must be received by NavBar component 
 })
```

I tried to do something like this:

```
    ...

    }).then((response) => {
     this.props.history.push({
        pathname: '/home',
     })
    return <NavBar propOne={propOneValue} />

    ...
```

But `this.props.propOne` in the NavBar (class based) component gets undefined. I think this might be caused by the fact that NavBar have been already rendered without props in one of the other components.

So my question is - can you use this.props.history.push to pass props to a different component than the pathname route one?

Comment: Is your component is having the props? its class based or functional component? can you plz put the snippet of the component from where the someFunction is called?

Comment: It is called from a class based component with a proper constructor

Comment: can you please give the code of component .

Comment: All right, so how can I pass that prop in this situation to the component that doesn't have a route in the react-router?

Comment: You need to transfer your propvalue from nav component to history .push right?

Comment: I need to transfer it to navbar component (without a pathname, so I can't use this.props.history.push directly). The form after getting a correct response from the API, takes user to the '/home' route - Home.js component that is included in the router, but I need the navbar component to receive the prop, while taking the user to the /home

Comment: Also, you need to display nav bar on home page ?

Comment: yep. It gets rendered in the main App.js file

Answer (score 5):

When using history to push, pass any data you want in the second argument for the push function

```
this.props.history.push('/yourPath', {prop1: someData});
```

and Then to access this data in the other component

```
const data = this.props.history.location.state;
// data will be {prop1: someData}
```

Answer (score 2):

In the 2nd block that you just edited, as soon the response is coming in it is redirecting to /home so return statement is not called as it has been now landed to home page. that's the reason you are getting propOne as undefined. To use in Home page give the props value to home page and in home page render you can push the required props value to nav bar.
**Use this way to pass the props value** :

```
this.props.history.push({
                pathname: "/home",
                state: {
                    propOne: propOneValue
                }
            });
```

And in Main Page to get the prop value: (if Main Page is a class based component else don't use this)

```
this.state = {
            propValue: this.props.location.state.propOne,
        }
```

then use the `propValue` in the component.

Try to `console.log(this.props.location)` and check what all the values you are getting to have clear view.

Main Page :

```
render() {
      return (
             <Nav  propVal={this.state.propValue}  />
        )
    }
```

Comment: The navbar is rendered in seperate from all this file App.js, not Home.js. And it needs to stay there for the application to look well. App.js also does not have a route

Answer (score 0):

I solved this actually.

Just for anyone with same problem: **just use Cookies or localStorage for moving variables if you have any problems with props**

But if anyone has an idea how to solve this with props, please feel free to share an answer